# Create a list of random values from given list in C# (MVC2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple model

```
public class OneModel
   {
      public string Email { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

And I created a simple list (OneModel datatype):

```
List<OneModel> someLists = new List<OneModel>{
            new OneModel{Name="A 1", Email="a1@some.com"},
            new OneModel{Name="A 2", Email="a2@some.com"},
            new OneModel{Name="A 3", Email="a3@some.com"},
            new OneModel{Name="B 1", Email="b1@some.com"},
            new OneModel{Name="C 1", Email="c1@some.com"},
  }
```

I want to create another list with random concatenated `Name` from first list, like as:
`List<string> ... {"A 1-A 3", "A 2-C 1",...}` or something like that.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming .NET Framework 4.0:

```
var random = new Random();
var result = new List<string>();
var count = random.Next(10, 20); // How many results do you want, really!?
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var query = from item in someLists
                order by random.Next()
                select item.Name;
    var items = query.Take(2);   // I assume you want two "names" in each item
    result.Add(string.Join("-", items));
}
```

Examine `result` for your random-length list of random randomness...

But what do you need it for...?

Comment: I want to learn more about list and get random values from generic list.